Connecting to a public network does not work on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
How do I connect to a public network with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS?
Under 22.04 LTS, immediately after connecting to the public network, a window opened in which I had to confirm the connection. Then I was online.
This doesn't work in 24.04 LTS.
What do I have to do so that such a window to confirm the connection opens?
